# Power series solutions to PDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, power-series

I am looking for literature on power series solutions to partial differential equations. In particular, I would like to understand the classification of singular surfaces which arise as a generalization of singular points of ODEs and to better understand logarithmic singularities, perhaps as a sort of generalization of the method of Frobenius. What is a good reference for these topics?